# How to increment version minor/patch based on the branch from which we merge

Tags: git, gitversion

We have a simple GitHubFlow workflow with `feature/*` and `bug/*` branches.

When things are merged to master, then the version gets bumped whatever we specify in the `GitVersion.yml` file (minor/patch).

```yaml
mode: Mainline
branches:
  main:
    regex: ^master$
    tag: ''
    # Increment is always the same regardless of the branch from which we are merging
    increment: Minor

  feature:
    regex: ^feature/
    tag: useBranchName
    increment: Minor
    source-branches:
    - main

  bug:
    regex: ^bug/
    tag: useBranchName
    increment: Patch
    source-branches:
    - main
```

However, I'd like to bump the minor or patch version depending on whether we merged from a feature or bug branch.

I'm using Squashing when merging to master.

Is there a way to do this please?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: I copy-pasted what I got. Hope it helps you. @JonasMohammed

Comment: Try adding a branch policy on main/master to validate the pr merge. The pr should get bumped correctly then when you complete the pr it will pull through the bumper version tag making main bump correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I was not able to increment the major, minor and patch versions based on the branch (the increment property inside each branch is ignored) so all merges to master increment the same way but with possibility to bump differently based on something added to the message e.g. Add `+f` (feature) to increment minor versions and `+b` (bug) to increment patch version.

```yaml
mode: Mainline
major-version-bump-message: '\+major'
minor-version-bump-message: '\+f'
patch-version-bump-message: '\+b'
branches:
  master:
    regex: ^master$
    tag: ""
    increment: Minor
    is-mainline: true

  feature:
    regex: ^feature/
    tag: useBranchName
    increment: Patch

  bug:
    regex: ^bug/
    tag: useBranchName
    increment: Patch
    source-branches:
      - master
```

Comment: Ahh I see. I couldn't get it working either so I simply went with feature/bugfix etc incrementing patch, master incrementing minor and manually incrementing major with commit message. Hopefully it becomes possible later!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```html
mode: Mainline
commit-message-incrementing: MergeMessageOnly
branches:
  main:
    regex: ^main$
    tag: ''
  feature:
    regex: ^feature/
    tag: useBranchName
    increment: Minor
  hotfix:
    regex: ^hotfix/
    tag: useBranchName
    increment: Patch
```

The minor version is incremented when merging from a feature branch.

The patch version is incremented when merging from a feature hotfix.